# Toggle display of unplaced labels with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am making a script that works with labels.

Is it possible to turn on/off the display of unplaced labels with PyQGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to 'click' the button using PyQGIS:

```py
for child in iface.mainWindow().children():
    if child.objectName() == 'mActionShowUnplacedLabels':
        child.trigger()
        break
```

You can get its current state with:

```py
child.isChecked()
```

[image] `False`

[image] `True`